# Are Aurora Stirling & Rick and Roy Hunter mass killers?

Tags: macross, robotech

In the Western *Robotech* composite series, much is made of the SDF-1’s loss of its reflex drive during its first fateful jump still within Earth’s atmosphere to Pluto, ripping Macross Island into space with it.

It is not until the novel series adaptation’s “continuing adventures,” Book 18, *The End of the Circle*, where we learn that many years into the future after the Pluto jump, Rick Hunter in command of the SDF-3 which has lost its own reflex drives, tasks the Robotech next generation Aurora Stirling (daughter of Max & Miriya) and Roy (his own son with Lisa Hayes) to get him a replacement from anywhere… or “any time.”

Aurora & Roy then hatch the plan to reach back into time and steal the SDF-1’s drive from the point in time of its jump to Pluto.

The loss of the drive during the jump to Pluto permanently gimped the SDF-1, and then served as Macross series’ biggest unresolved mystery as well as its most profound plot mechanism. For example, in Dolza’s rain of terror, which nearly obliterated the Earth, the SDF-1 was forced to base itself on Earth and was unable to jump to repel Dolza’s armada. Hundreds of millions if not trillions died in Dolza’s attack.

Is Rick Hunter, along with Aurora and Roy who actually executed the theft, to blame for the untold suffering and death which occurred during Macross series because the SDF-1 couldn’t jump as it should have been able to throughout the entirety of the *Macross* era? Did any of the stories address the decision and impact of their *The End of the Circle* time heist on the lives of people in *Macross* era?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is classic paradox.  The SDF-1's engines disappeared without explanation (other than a space-fold that close to a gravitational body warped the spacefold engines right out of the universe by overload).  The SDF-1's engines disappeared; the physics of the singularity that the SDF-3 found itself inside (during the plot of *The End of the Circle*) made such time-space theft possible.

As for the ramifications of the theft, the SDF-1's engines were already affected by the close-surface space-folding.  Rather than have them escape the universe into otherspace between the universes, Aurora Sterling and Roy Hunter managed to "grab onto" the spacefold drives and place them into the SDF-3's missing engine compartment.  The SDF-1's engines were going to be gone anyway; the timeline was not affected by the theft.

Also, Protoculture as a quasi-sentient force of nature could have enabled such a snatch-and-replace to happen anyway.

Comment: This is great response. Based on this I can accept the drive was lost to SDF-1 in any and all case, and was salvaged from that loss to assist SDF-3 by grace. If it wasn’t repurposed, SDF-1 still wasn’t recovering it.